# Bind a DropDownList to IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net

I have a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Datarow> getInfo (string test)
{
    some functionality and adds two columns in datatable dt.

   now how can i return dt from this method (question 1)
}
```

I have to bind the method returned value to a dropdown list named `ddlist` .

How can i make it possible

(question no 2.)
.. when i tried i get the message that can not bind ienumerable . . . .

please help me out.

Comment: If I were you I'd pick a title for the question that reflected the nature of the question.

Comment: Your question's title in no way says anything about your question's subject.

Comment: Your Q needs proper formatting and well structured query...

Comment: Sorry about that. i am trying to edit my title.

Comment: is there any way i can delete this question and begin new

Comment: I updated your title - is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the method to return a datatable or loop through the IEnumerable and add the list items manually.

Check this blog post for another approach to what you're trying to do. http://geekswithblogs.net/mikethomas/archive/2007/01/15/103686.aspx

Code sample from blog (not mine):

```
public IEnumerable GetDataSource() {
    string key = "CodeDrowDownListTest_" + CodeName;

    object item = Page.Cache.Get(key);
    if (item == null)
    {
        item = GetDataFromDB();
        Page.Cache.Insert(key, item, null, System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    return (IEnumerable)item; }

 public override void DataBind() {
    this.DataSource = GetDataSource();
    this.DataTextField = "Text";
    this.DataValueField = "Value";

    base.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have to have method as public Ienumerable <datarow>getinfo , can i simply return item if i have datatable to be returned?